# How can I handle a variable number of input lines in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, if-statement, hash

I am working with a Perl script where I need to work with MTA's logs. Below is the query which I want to work with.

> ```
> sh-3.2# cat /var/log/pmta/File_name-2017-03-23*|egrep 'email.domain.com'|cut -d, -f6|cut -d- -f1|sort|uniq -c
> ```

The output of this query is stored in `$case8Q1`.

```
   310 blk
  1279 hrd
    87 sft
144056 success
    18 unk
```

As you can see above query gives 5 values but this is not always the case. It can also give like this. So the number of rows may vary each time (2 or 3 or 4 or max 5)

```
   310 blk
144056 success
    18 unk
```

below is the sample code which gives the wrong result

```
sub get_stats {

    $case8Q1 =~ s/^\s+//;

    @case8Q1_split = split( '\n', $case8Q1 );

    @first_part    = split( ' ',  $case8Q1_split[0] );
    @second_part   = split( ' ',  $case8Q1_split[1] );
    @third_part    = split( ' ',  $case8Q1_split[2] );
    @fourth_part   = split( ' ',  $case8Q1_split[3] );
    @fifth_part    = split( ' ',  $case8Q1_split[4] );

    if ( $first_part[1] eq 'blk' ) {
        $report{Block} = $first_part[0];
    }
    elsif ( $first_part[1] eq 'hrd' ) {
        $report{Hard} = $first_part[0];
    }
    elsif ( $first_part[1] eq 'sft' ) {
        $report{Soft} = $first_part[0];
    }
    elsif ( $first_part[1] eq 'success' ) {
        $report{Success} = $first_part[0];
    }
    elsif ( $first_part[1] eq 'unk' ) {
        $report{Unknown} = $first_part[0];
    }

    # rest ifelse blocks so on........!
}
```

where report is hash `%report`.

Can someone please help me how can operate it from here.

I have all the values but if I go with normal `if`-`else` like above it will take at least 25 `blocks.

Let me know please if this is not clear.

Source log sample:

```
b,email@aol.com,206.1.1.8,2017-03-23 00:01:11-0700,<14901.eb201.TCR2.338351.18567117907MSOSI1.152‌​OSIMS@email.domain.c‌​om>,sft-routing-erro‌​rs,4.4.4 (unable to route: dns lookup failure),
b,email@gmail.com,206.9.1.8,2017-03-23 00:02:13-0700,<149019.eb201.TCR2.338351.18567119237MSOSI1.15‌​2OSIMS@email.domain.‌​com>,sft-no-answer-f‌​rom-host,4.4.1 (no answer from host), 
b,email@gmail.com,206.1.1.5,2017-03-23 03:43:36-0700,<149020.eb201.TCR2.338656.18570260933MSOSI1.15‌​2OSIMS@email.domain.‌​com>,sft-server-rela‌​ted,4.3.2 (system not accepting network messages),smtp;421 Too many concurrent SMTP connections 
b,email@yahoo.com,,2017-03-23 03:54:44-0700,<149019.eb201.TCR2.338351.18567013352MSOSI1.15‌​2OSIMS@email.domain.‌​com>,sft-message-exp‌​ired,4.4.7 (delivery time expired), 
b,email@msn.com,206.1.1.1,2017-03-23 05:04:20-0700,<14902666.eb201.TCR2.3831.2620484MSOSI6374125.‌​102OSIMS@email.domai‌​n.com>,hrd-invalid-m‌​ailbox,5.0.0 (undefined status),smtp;550 Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable 
b,email@msn.com,206.1.1.1,2017-03-23 05:04:20-0700,<14902666.eb201.TCR2.3831.2620484MSOSI6374125.‌​102OSIMS@email.domai‌​n.com>,hrd-invalid-d‌​omain,5.0.0 (undefined status),smtp;550 Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable 
b,email@aol.com.com,66.1.1.1,2017-03-23 05:08:44-0700,<149021.eb201.KCR2.021089.566131285MSOSI1.89OS‌​IMS@email.domain.com‌​>,unk-other,4.0.0 (undefined status),smtp;451 Your domain is not configured to use this MX host.
b,email@gmail.com,206.1.1.1,2017-03-23 05:13:22-0700,<1490206.eb201.KCR2.6637.56206428MSOSI1.102OSI‌​MS@email.domain.com>‌​,blk-bad-connection,‌​4.4.2 (bad connection), 
b,email@qq.com.com,206.1.1.1,2017-03-23 05:13:22-0700,<1490206.eb201.KCR2.6637.56206428MSOSI1.102OSI‌​MS@email.domain.com>‌​,blk-spam-related,4.‌​4.2 (bad connection),
```

Here the requirment goes further. I need domain count as will example -

```
Date          Domain       Success Block Soft Hard Unknown
2017-03-23    gmail         1       1   1   1   1    1
2017-03-23    yahoo         1       1   1   1   1    1
2017-03-23    msn           1       1   1   1   1    1
2017-03-23    aol           1       1   1   1   1    1
2017-03-23    other domain  1       1   1   1   1    1
```

my problem is with other domain which contains all the domain except gmail, yahoo, msn, hotmail and aol.
count 1 is just example it can be 0.

Comment: It's a bit unclear, because I think you're taking a MUCH harder approach than you need to. Lots of cuts/sort/unique says to me that you should consider rewriting stuff in pure `perl`. To that end - some sample input and desired output would be the way to go.

Comment: `sh-3.2#` looks like a command line prompt, but from what you say it sounds like you're using backticks in your Perl program. Which is it?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am using backtick. but if there is other way I can do so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so - you've started off doing this a really hard way, because ... `perl` can natively do everything that cut/sort/uniq do anyway.

I can't rewrite that for you without some sample input, but ... I think you should consider that.

You should also not use global vars, and use lexical ones with `my`.

And - as you've noticed - if you're numbering your variable names, you really should be considering an array.

So something like this:

```
use Data::Dumper
my @stuff = map { [split] } split( "\n", $case8Q1 );
print Dumper \@stuff;
```

Gives you:

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            '310',
            'blk'
          ],
          [
            '1279',
            'hrd'
          ],
          [
            '87',
            'sft'
          ],
          [
            '144056',
            'success'
          ],
          [
            '18',
            'unk'
          ]
        ];
```

But you can go one step further, because you don't actually need to parse this into a data structure at all:

```
   my %data =  reverse $case8Q1 =~ m/(\d+) (\w+)/g;
   print Dumper \%data;
```

Which then gives you:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'hrd' => '1279',
          'sft' => '87',
          'blk' => '310',
          'unk' => '18',
          'success' => '144056'
        };
```

You can then translate that into your 'report' by using again, a key-value lookup:

```
my %keyword_for = ( 
    "blk" => "Block",
    "hrd" => "Hard",
    "sft" => "Soft",
    "success" => "Success",
    "unk" => "Unknown",
    );

foreach my $key ( keys %data ) { 
   $report{$keyword_for{$key}} = $data{$key}; 
}
```

And that gives you:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'Soft' => '87',
          'Unknown' => '18',
          'Success' => '144056',
          'Block' => '310',
          'Hard' => '1279'
        };
```

Or take it a step further still and inline the transformation using `map`:

```
my %report =   map { m/(\d+) (\w+)/ 
                 && $keyword_for{$2} // $2 => $1 } split "\n", $case8Q1;
print Dumper \%report;
```

And as you say you want *all* the values to be populated.... actually I'd suggest not doing that, and handling 'undefined' properly when generating output with something like:

```
my @field_order = qw ( Block Hard Soft Success Unknown this_field_missing ); 
print join "\t", @field_order,"\n";
print join "\t", ( map { $report{$_} // 0 } @field_order),"\n";
```

This way you get defined-order output, where hashes *don't* do defined-order. This gives:

```
Block   Hard    Soft    Success Unknown this_field_missing  
310     1279    87      144056  18      0
```

But if you really want to backfill your empty hash with zero values:

```
$report{$_} //= 0 for values %keyword_for;
```

However, now you've posted some logs to go with your question - the problem's *much* simpler:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

#configure it:
my %keyword_for = (
   "blk"     => "Block",
   "hrd"     => "Hard",
   "sft"     => "Soft",
   "success" => "Success",
   "unk"     => "Unknown",
);
#set output order - last field is for illustration purposes
my @field_order = qw ( Block Hard Soft Success Unknown this_field_missing );

my %count_of;
#iterate 'STDIN' or files specified to command line.
#So you can 'thisscript.pl /var/log/pmta/File_name-2017-03-23*'
while (<>) {
   #split the line on commas
   my ( $id, $em_addr, $ip, $timestamp, $msg_id, $code, $desc ) = split /,/;
   #require msg_id contains '@email.domain.com'. 
   next unless $msg_id =~ m/\@email\.domain\.com/;
   #split the status field on dash, extracting first word. 
   my ($status) = $code =~ m/^(\w+)-/;
   #update the count - reference the 'keyword for' hash first, 
   #but insert 'raw' if it's something new. 
   $count_of{ $keyword_for{$status} // $status }++;
}

#print a header row (tab sep)
print join "\t", @field_order, "\n";
#print the rest of the values. 
#map is so 'missing' fields get zeros, not 'undefined'. 
print join "\t", ( map { $count_of{$_} // 0 } @field_order ), "\n";
```

And given the small sample you've posted, this outputs:

```
Block   Hard    Soft    Success Unknown this_field_missing  
2       2       4       0       1       0
```

Comment: thank you. it is really helpful. now from here I still need one thing. as I said the number of rows may varies from minimum 0 to max 5.   so when it comes only 3, the missing values should have 0.                                                                       $VAR1 = {
          'Soft' => '87',
          'Unknown' => '0',
          'Success' => '144056',
          'Block' => '310',
          'Hard' => '0'
        };

Comment: `$report{$_} //= 0 for keys %keyword_for;` But honestly, I'd usually 'filter' that as you're generating your output.

Comment: I'll give sample input data so that I can proceed with your recommendation .

Comment: I don't know how to format logs in comment box.. please it in my next comment and copy in your notepad

Comment: I added my further requirement and edited my question with a table domain wise. I know this is possible but I am stuck at other domain stats

Comment: If you have a new question, then ask a new question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43003466/i-am-working-on-perl-script-and-i-need-to-parse-the-logs-given-below

Comment: your latest code is giving - Use of uninitialized value $status in hash element at test2.pl line 28, <> line 11872

Comment: Means on line 11872 of your file (which may be the last) there's no match for the `$status` regex - e.g. `m/^(\w+)-/`, which may mean there's no comma-sep fields on that line.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know what result you want, but I would do the backticks in list context so that the lines are already separated, and replace the chain of `if`/`elsif` with a simple hash lookup

This sample code builds a hash `%report` the same as yours, and returns a reference to it. I've had to assume that you're using backticks as it seems the most likely. **Sobrique** is correct that your shell code should also be done in Perl

```
my %map = (
    blk     => 'Block',
    hrd     => 'Soft',
    sft     => 'Block',
    success => 'Success',
    unk     => 'Unknown',
);

my $cmd = q{cat /var/log/pmta/File_name-2017-03-23*|egrep 'email.domain.com'|cut -d, -f6|cut -d- -f1|sort|uniq -c};

sub get_stats {

    my %report;

    for ( `$cmd` ) {

        my ($val, $type) = split;

        $report{$map{$type}} = $val;
    }

    \%report;
}
```

Comment: It's print nothing when I tried it.                                                                print Dumper \%report; I mean the output is -----   $VAR1 = {};

Comment: @PankajKumar: That will be because the shell command doesn't produce anything. I've copied it from your question so I can't tell what's wrong with it.